# Asynchronous query status functions only available in same session?

Tags: sql, postgresql, asynchronous, postgresql-9.5, dblink

My aim was to have a web service fire off an asynchronous query using the following mechanism:

```
select dblink_connect('asyncconnect', 'host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=theking password=pass');  
select dblink_send_query('asyncconnect', 'perform pg_sleep(60)); --represents som elong running query/function
```

After having fired off that process, I wanted to come back at a later time and check up on its progress, in a **new client instance**, by using the following call:

```
SELECT * from dblink_is_busy('asyncconnect');
```

However, this is not working, instead I receive an error:

> ERROR: connection "asyncconnect" not available.

This is despite the async query from initial dispatch still running.

Also, if I try this query:

```
select * from dblink_get_connections()
```

Nothing returns.

This can be recreated by running the above scenario with two different PostgreSQL clients: I used dbeaver to connect and dispatch the first worker query and sqlworkbench to try and get query status. Both connected to same server and DB obviously.

Now, if I perform everything in one client, then it works as expected.

However, the nature of asynchronous processing is that you fire something off, then come back later and check up it for status or result, regardless of the session.

Is this not the case as far as PostgreSQL is concerned?

I have created a workaround by having the long running process post its status to a table that I can then query, but it seems the status functions provided should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dblink connection is only available in the database session that created it.

So yes, you will have to use a different technique, like you do in your workaround. In that case you don't need dblink at all. It is just not the tool for what you want.

Comment: That offers some clarity, wish the documentation would state that, at least what I have seen doesn't say that. I still do need to use the dblink_send_query, because I cannot wait around for it to be done. Thanks for the information.

Comment: You can glean it from the documentation: *The connection will persist until closed or until the database session is ended.* I guess nobody thought of the possibility that anybody would assume that a dblink connection can be reused outside the database session...

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did see that before. The problem is, what do they mean by session. I can instantiate a client that will call the function that dispatches the asynchronous query, then close that client, yet the query is left running as expected, it's not shut down. So, is it the client session or is it the query execution session? It cannot be the client session because I have closed the it and yet the query keeps running. in the connection created. Thanks again.

Comment: In database jargon, a session lasts from the time where you connect to the database to the time when you disconnect. What you describe should only happen if you don't close the client in a clean fashion - then the backend doesn't know the client is gone.

Comment: Then what must be happening is that the combination of: dblink_connect
and dblink_send_query are creating some sort of internal session. Because what I describe doing is what I have done and it works, ie, I instantiate a client, fire off the command then close my client, and the query keeps running. That's how I expect asynchronous query dispatch to work.

Comment: @Kenobi unfortunately postgres is totally synchronous. Which means there is no way to run any async job from a client connection unless you specifically create it using a background worker process (in which case it's still not run from client).

Comment: @user64204 No, you can send database statements asynchronously. But you cannot send a query in one connection and receive the answer in a different connection. See the difference?

Answer (score 0):

you can send an async query with dbink that will persist after dblink_disconnect has successfully disconnected, but only if it not labelled as VOLATILE, if it is a function call.

Also, a CREATE TABLE that uses a SELECT to gather the rows can be sent with dblink_send_query, and before it is finished, dblink_disconnect will not interrupt the process, and in the parent session a disconnection also will not interrupt. Then, later another session can wait for and read the created table.

example:

```
set search_path = hdb ;

select dblink_connect('connection', 'dbname=database') ;

select dblink_send_query ( '_hdb' , 'create table ____ as select * from ____ JOIN _______ JOIN etc ;' ) ;

select dblink_disconnect('_hdb');
```